# How to properly manage inputs in a Sinatra web page

Tags: javascript, sinatra

I am working on a super simple Sinatra app for demo purposes and I am wondering if there is a better way to implement it.

The ruby program is super simple (note: only the relevant part is pasted below):

```
get '/' do
    redis = Redis.new
    redis = Redis.new(:host => settings.redis, :port => 6379)
    redis.incr("pageviews")

    @pageviews = redis.get("pageviews")
    @hostname = Socket.gethostname

    erb :webapp 
end #get /

post '/increase' do
    redis = Redis.new
    redis = Redis.new(:host => settings.redis, :port => 6379)
    redis.incr("pageviews")

    @pageviews = redis.get("pageviews")
    @hostname = Socket.gethostname
    redirect '/'

end #post /increase
```

And then my html is even easier (note: only the relevant part is pasted below):

```
        <em style="color: blue; font-style: italic"> Views count (<%= @pageviews %>):</em>

        <form method="post" action="/increase">
            <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>
        </form>
```

When you load the home page the counter increases by 1. When you click the submit button the counter increases by 2 (one because of the action I submit and one because of the redirect to the home page). That's fine. That's what I want.

However, because of how Sinatra works, when I push the Submit button what happens is that basically the entire page reloads. For a simple page like this it's fine but I fear that for a more complex app reloading the entire web page may be a too heavy of an operation. Certainly not elegant.

I am wondering if I am trying to stretch Sinatra too much (and if I want to do those things I should switch to something like Angular) or if there are ways that I can use in Sinatra to do that "increase" without having to call a method + the redirect to `/`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the entire page, you have two options: either use iframes (please don't use iframes), or use a background communication mechanism in JavaScript, like AJAX or WebSockets. Sinatra can handle AJAX request with ease. Now, if you want Sinatra to generate the JavaScript code to perform the AJAX request like some web frameworks do (like Angular, for example), then no, Sinatra doesn't do that. You have to implement the JavaScript by yourself. Pro tip: use jQuery for that, it will make your life easier.